# What to do if network fails before POST response can be read?

Tags: rest, post, error-handling

When accessing a REST service from a client that has an unreliable network connection (e.g., some crappy cell network), what are some best practices for handling an error where the network connection drops before the response to a POST can be read. Since POSTs are not idempotent, it's unsafe to naively retry. Are there best practices for this? Assume I'm also designing the service end of this, so there are no constraints on that end of the wire either.

Comment: If POST fails, you say it cannot be retried, so this is an unrecoverable error. So your only choice is error handling, for example showing an error message.

Comment: Yes, in the naive case it's unsafe to retry, because that may create a second resource when only one was desired. I'm just curious if there are service design patterns and/or best practices to get around this. Bothering the user to force them to figure out what to do is a last resort IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Write a protocol which does not allow to create a second resource when the client did not consume the first one. For example, after GETting the resource, the client should POST back that it consumed it, so the service can safely create another one when the next GET arrives. If no verification POST arrives, the server should respond every subsequent GETs by sending the same resource which was created for the first GET (this may be client-specific). -- This way you can safely repeat the GET after the predefined timeout interval elapses. (If the number of repeats exceeds a given value, it means that you have a permanent network or service error, about which you will have to notify the user.)